# Filter lookup with fetchXML and special character '&' does not work

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, ampersand, fetchxml

I am currently trying to filter a lookup field in Dynamics 365 CRM using a fetchXML in a javascript. I have to view all the products with a custom text field ('my_variantstatus') not equal to 'R&D Stage' (and some other values). I have a problem with the character "&".

Here is my filter xml:

```
var filterXml = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='my_variantstatus' operator='ne' value='R&amp;D stage'/><condition attribute='my_variantstatus' operator='ne' value='Discontinued'/></filter>";
```

I have already tried remplacing the ampersand '&' with : `\&`, `&amp;`, `&#38;`, `encodeURIComponent('R&D stage')`, `%26` but none of them worked.

Please note that the script works well when I try to filter without the ampersand ('RD stage') and that it does not work with any other special character as well (quote, <, >, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is an usual problem, try the encoding to solve it.

```
var item = 'R&D stage';
var encodedItem = encodeURIComponent(item);

var filterXml = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='my_variantstatus' operator='ne' value= '"+ encodedItem +"'/><condition attribute='my_variantstatus' operator='ne' value='Discontinued'/></filter>";
```

Comment: It did not work. `encodeURIComponent` just replaces the ampersand by `%26` and the space by `%20`, so now it filters `R%26D%20stage` (tested).

Comment: @ThibC I’m not sure without seeing the whole code, this code worked for me in the past. https://www.armanino.com/articles/dynamics-crm-2011-custom-filtered-lookup-display-error/ check this blog as well